# okhttp POST request body undefined

Tags: java, android, node.js, express, okhttp

I am using Node with express for the server and okhttp for Android client. I am trying to send a post request to the server using the code below:

```
FormBody.Builder bodyBuilder = new FormBody.Builder();
for (String key : bodyParams.keySet())
    bodyBuilder.add(key, bodyParams.get(key));

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(urlBuilder.build())
        .post(bodyBuilder.build())
        .build();

mHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(callback);
```

And on the server, I set up express with body parser and else:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
```

And handles the post request here:

```
app.post(CONSTANTS.ROUTES.USER.REGISTER, function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body);
    return;
}
```

However, the req.body is always undefined, okhttp performs normally with get requests and query parameters but I've tried formBody and

```
RequestBody.create(JSON, json)
```

method as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34180100/4619734), none worked, "req.body" always shows as undefined. Can any one help me with this?

okhttp version: 3.4.1

OS: El Capitan

Node: 6.3.0

Comment: Rather you should use Android Volley for Http request in android:
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html

Comment: Try this link : Feel free to ask if help required..
[OKHttp post implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135338/okhttp-library-networkonmainthreadexception-on-simple-post/38244995#38244995)

Comment: I would stick with this for now unless it is proven that okhttp does not handle post request, and the link provided was not helpful to my situation