# Retrofit Synchronous Requests error

Tags: android

I'm write this code for call  retrofit Synchronous Requests :

```
public String LOGININTO() throws IOException {
     final String[] message = {""};
     LOGININTERFACE taskService = ServiceGenerator.createService(LOGININTERFACE.class);
     Call<LGOINMODEL> tasks = taskService.savePost("0016642902","0016642902","password");
     LGOINMODEL model=null;
     model=tasks.execute().body();
     return "OK";
}
```

but when run my code get this error:
at

> `Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>   retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:91)`

How can I solve that Problem?

thanks.

Comment: please specify what error exactly u r getting in detail

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28135573/3505534

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your execution on a `new Thread()`:

```
public String LOGININTO() throws IOException {
 final String[] message = {""};
 LOGININTERFACE taskService = ServiceGenerator.createService(LOGININTERFACE.class);
 Call<LGOINMODEL> tasks = taskService.savePost("0016642902","0016642902","password");
 LGOINMODEL model=null;
 Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       model=tasks.execute().body();
    }
 });
 thread.start();

 return "OK";
}
```